# Using addJoin in Native SQL Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am using Hibernate 3.2.5 for my application.

I have a Dept table and an Employees table.

**Dept.java**

```
private int deptId;
private String deptName;
private Map empMap = new HashMap();
//Getters and Setters
```

**Employees.java**

```
private int empId;
private String empName;
private int deptId;
private int age;
private String sex;
private Dept dept;
```

**HBM Mapping file**

```
<class name="com.jdbc.Dept" table="dept">
  <id name="deptId" type="integer" column="DEPT_ID">
      <generator class="assigned"></generator>
  </id>  
  <property name="deptName">
      <column name="DEPT_NAME"></column>
  </property>    
  <map name="empMap" inverse="false" cascade="all" lazy="true">
      <key column="DEPT_ID"></key>
      <map-key formula="EMP_ID" type="integer"></map-key>
      <one-to-many class="com.jdbc.Employees"/>
  </map>
```

Below is the code for Native SQL:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("Select d.*, e.* from Dept d,Emp e where d.DEPT_ID = e.DEPT_ID")
                .addEntity("department",Dept.class)
                .addJoin("e","department.empMap");
        List<Dept> departments = query.list();
        for(Dept depart :departments)
            System.out.println(depart.getDeptId());
```

**Exception:**

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
at com.jdbc.HibernateStartup.main(HibernateStartup.java:75)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:111)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:145)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3295)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1913)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getInt(OracleResultSet.java:1562)
at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.get(IntegerType.java:28)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:163)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:154)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.readIndex(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:708)
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap.readFrom(PersistentMap.java:258)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElement(Loader.java:1008)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.readCollectionElements(Loader.java:646)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:591)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:701)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
```

In the doc, they are using the `addJoin` method which takes 1 parameter but for me, it is asking for two parameters (since I am using v3.2.5 and the doc is on v3.3)

Kindly let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument in `.addEntity("department",Dept.class)` is a table alias, and looking at your SQL query the right value is `"d"` and not `"department"`.

You should make this change here too: `.addJoin("e","department.empMap");`, replacing `"department.empMap"` with `"d.empMap"`.